# mesh moving forward without key frames

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh

In blender I deleted keyframes after 400, but my character still moving forward continously.

My character does not stop in any place. How I stop it? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HyapnNHXoWfBAMFr7GfXsN1l6bqD_Gbd/view?usp=sharing you can see it after

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before and got the same answer that you got now? It's the _Follow Path_ constraint.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the "follow path constraints" on belly.001:

[image]

either delete it, or keyframe it via offset or check "clamp" in your Nurbspath:

[image]

Comment: Sir explain briefly how to i do it